# Magento catalog product price

Tags: php, magento

Where in code I can change "special price" or just change price for each product magento show?

I found how to change price in checkout,

config.xml:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                    <class>discounts/observer</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

and observer:

```
    <?php

class <namespace>_<module>_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
    {
        // Get the quote item
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();

        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        // Load the custom price
        $price = $this->_getPriceByItem($item);

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

    protected function _getPriceByItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item)
    {
        $price = null;

        $price = 10;

        return $price;
    }
}
```

this code set all price to 10$, but only in "My cart".

At first I want to change `frontend -> events -> THIS EVENT`, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using the catalog_product_load_after event, that is called directly after the model is loaded every time and not only in the cart.

Comment: I know that, just show my work code, this part of code change price in checkout, I can't find how to change it on site!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question :(